# Sticky floating bar : accurate position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

I am looking for a better solution to sticky bar issue.

The '-----' between 2nd & 3rd box is a threshold from where the sticky bar should get display. When its displayed, it overlaps the 3rd box completely.

In the real solution, I have added css (margin-top) using jquery to push this element below; but the problem is it's lagging in Firefox. One can see this space for fractions of seconds on UI.

What is the best solution to achieve the output ( or avoid margin-top) ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function toggleDock() {
   
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.second').offset().top+$('.second').height()) {
      $('.sticky').show();
    }
    else {
      $('.sticky').hide();
    }
  }
  
  $(window).bind('scroll',toggleDock);
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
 .sticky {
   height: 80px;
   border: 1px dotted green;
   margin: 20px 0;
   display: none;
   position: sticky;
   top: 20px;
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='page docked'>
<div class='sticky'>
 </div>
  
<div class='box'>
  First 
</div>
<div class='box second' >
  2nd
</div>

  -------
<div class='box'>
  3rd
</div>
<div class='box'>
  4th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  5th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  6th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  7th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  8th
</div>
  
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I think you need to keep your `sticky` div in the normal flow, and `position: sticky` is probably not the right choice here. Here is an example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function toggleDock() {
   
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.second').offset().top+$('.second').height()) {
      $('.sticky').show();
    }
    else {
      $('.sticky').hide();
    }
  }
  
  $(window).bind('scroll',toggleDock);
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.sticky {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  margin: 20px 0;
  top: 40px;
  display: none;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='page docked'>
  
<div class='box'>
  First 
</div>
<div class='box second' >
  2nd
</div>

  -------
<div class='sticky'>
</div>

<div class='box'>
  3rd
</div>
<div class='box'>
  4th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  5th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  6th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  7th
</div>
<div class='box'>
  8th
</div>
  
  
</body>
```

A nice document about CSS flow : http://marksheet.io/css-the-flow.html

`position: sticky` is not detailed there, but from [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), you'll see that a `sticky` element is positioned relatively to its containing element when it's visible, and becomes `fixed` (that is, it is taken out of the normal document flow) when its containing element is not visible :

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry .. but it seems I was not able to put what is the desired expectation.

If you observed , when sticky is displayed,  it should push the 3rd box below and make some space for the sticky.

Whats happening currently or in my solution as well, it overlaps the 3rd box. That is not what I want.

Comment: Hi @Robin, I think I understand better. Can you please try the updated code snippet ? It actually puts the `sticky` div back into the normal flow, and uses the `hide/show` functions that internally toggle the `display` CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `position: sticky`. Using `position: fixed` alternatively will help you.

```
.sticky {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: none;
  top: 20px;
  background: green;

  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); /* subtract the 20px taken by the left and right margins */
```

}